# Does "perpendicular phase incoherence" satisfy the triangle inequality?

Tags: geometry, statistics, inequality, complex-numbers, circles

Let $S$ be the unit circle in the complex plane,
$$ S = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| = 1\}. $$

> For values $z_1^{(1)},z_1^{(2)},z_2^{(1)},z_2^{(2)},\ldots,z_k^{(1)},z_k^{(2)} \in S$, letting
> \begin{align*}
>  A &:= \left|\sum_{j=1}^k z_j^{(1)}z_j^{(2)}\right| \\
>  B_1 &:= \left|\sum_{j=1}^k z_j^{(1)}\right| \\
>  B_2 &:= \left|\sum_{j=1}^k z_j^{(2)}\right|,
>  \end{align*}
> do we necessarily have that
> $$ \hspace{30mm} \sqrt{k^2 - A^2} \leq \sqrt{k^2 - B_1^2} \, + \sqrt{k^2 - B_2^2} \, ? \hspace{30mm} (\ast) $$

---

**Context.** In the question [Does pairwise phase incoherence satisfy the triangle inequality?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4770068/222867), I asked whether we necessarily have that

\begin{equation} \hspace{30mm} A \geq B_1 + B_2 - k, \hspace{30mm} (1) \end{equation}

and if not, then whether we necessarily at least have that
\begin{equation} \hspace{27mm} A^2 \geq B_1^2 + B_2^2 - k^2. \hspace{28mm} (2) \end{equation}

Equation (1) has a geometric interpretation in terms of whether the direct (i.e. radial) distance from the centre of gravity of mass on the unit circle to the unit circle itself fulfils a kind of triangle inequality with respect to addition of angles on the unit circle. Equation (2) is a weaker equation in which "distance to the unit circle" is replaced by "1 minus the square of the distance to the origin". It turned out that (2) does not necessarily hold, and therefore (1) also does not necessarily hold.

But now I realise that with regards to (2), I asked "the wrong question". Namely, (2) does not really have any simple geometric interpretation; but by taking the square root of the distance function in (2), I get an even weaker equation, namely ($\ast$), which has the same geometric interpretation as (1) except with "radial distance" replaced by "perpendicular-to-radial distance".

I'm pretty sure that the counterexample given to (2) in the linked question will not be a counterexample to ($\ast$), as one can physically draw that counterexample and get a literal triangle whose triangle inequality corresponds to it not being a counterexample to ($\ast$).

The question I'm asking is relevant to time-series analysis, as described in the linked question.

Comment: I've now asked the question at MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/q/457444/15570

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to argue similarly to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4731621/), but did not succeed. (Doesn't mean it is not possible.) Here is another attack direction:

**Claim.** Let $u, v, w \in \Bbb C^k$, $0 \not = ||u|| = ||v|| = ||w|| = s$. If $A = |\langle u, v \rangle|$, $B_1 = |\langle u,w \rangle|$, $B_2 = |\langle v,w\rangle|$, then $\sqrt{s^4 - A^2} \le \sqrt{s^4 - B_1^2} + \sqrt{s^4 - B_2^2}$.

The claim is (a bit) stronger than the one in the question (when translating, don't forget about the conjugates; my $v$ would be the conjugate of a renormalized $z^{(2)}$). However it only needs to be proved for $k = 3$, since all the action goes in the $\Bbb C$-linear span of $u, v, w$, and the inequality is scale-independent (fix $s = 1$). $100000$ Monte-Carlo iterations indicate its plausiblility.

Let a matrix $M$ have $u,v,w$ as its columns. By [Schur decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition) of $M$ (= a certain unitary change of basis), WLOG $u = (a,0,0), v = (b,c,0), w = (d,e,f)$, where $|a|^2 = |b|^2 + |c|^2 = |d|^2 + |e|^2 + |f|^2 = 1$. So, using real coordinates, we need to check if the inequality holds on a 9-dimensional subset of $\Bbb R^{12}$ (that is also a manifold and a product of affine varieties).

I am not familiar with algorithms in real algebraic geometry or specialized CAS, but the dimensions tell me that it won't be easy for any of them, if even possible. However the equations of the variety are not complicated (the inequality in real coordinates is going to be a monster). Maybe a knowledgeable person would continue this line of reasoning.

Comment: +1 
I expect that the real counterpart of Claim has the following geometrical reduction. For vectors $x,y\in\mathbb R^n$ let $\angle xy$ be the (smaller) angle between them.  Then $A=s\cos\angle uv$, $B_1=s\cos\angle uw$, and $B_2=s\cos\angle vw$. Then the inequality reduces to $$\sin\angle uv\le\sin\angle uw+\sin\angle vw,$$ that is the area of the triangle spanned by $u$ and $v$ is not bigger than the sum of areas of triangles spanned by $u$ and $w$ and by $v$ and $w$.